# Read Broker configuration from activemq.xml file and start Broker using Java code

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I want to read the some_dir/activemq.xml file so that I can create a broker using org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService , which will have all the configuration as per the provided file. I tried to set the properties programmatically :

```
TransportConnector tc = new TransportConnector();
    tc.setName("openwire");
    tc.setUri(new URI("tcp://localhost:61616?trace=true"));
    
    List<TransportConnector> tcList = new ArrayList<TransportConnector>();
    tcList.add(tc);
    broker.setTransportConnectors(tcList);
    
    DiscoveryNetworkConnector nc =  new DiscoveryNetworkConnector();
    nc.setName("Q:broker1->broker2");
    nc.setUri(new URI("static:(tcp://localhost:61616)"));
    nc.setDuplex(false);
    nc.setDecreaseNetworkConsumerPriority(false);
    nc.setNetworkTTL(2);
    nc.setDynamicOnly(true);
    
    List<DiscoveryNetworkConnector> ncList = new ArrayList<DiscoveryNetworkConnector>();
    ncList.add(nc);
    
    broker.setNetworkConnectors(ncList);
    
    
    System.out.println(broker);
    //broker.startTransportConnector(tc);
    //broker.startAllConnectors();
    broker.start();
```

but it is lengthy.
Is there any way i can do  broker.readConfigFile("/conf/activemq.xml")

OR it is not possible(though i think it is). So the only way to start broker is from command line and write java clients(producer/consumer) to connect to that.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService broker = org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(new URI("xbean:file:some_dir/activemq.xml"));
broker.start();
```

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
>   <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
>   <version>5.xx.x</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection.html

Comment: class not found exception went on solving each: org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Constraint
org/eclipse/jetty/server/UserIdentity
org/eclipse/jetty/util/component/AbstractLifeCycle
org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService
io/fabric8/insight/log/support/LogQuerySupportMBean
io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery
org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
org/apache/xbean/spring/context/impl/URIEditor
org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
org/springframework/core/NestedRuntimeException
org/springframework/beans/BeansException ,  which jars to add as no luck still:(

Comment: check my update, did you have activemq-all dependency added ?

Comment: yes activemq-all-5.11.1.jar and kahadb-5.5.0.jar was added hence it is working with other variations/examples except passing conf file

Comment: normally you need all jar's in the /apache-activemq-5.xx.x/lib folder